# This code is about opening and closing file

Tags: c#

I can read  fine.  I have several files as I open and reopen them  I
will get an error after a few times

> The process cannot access the
> file D:.csv because it is being used by another process

Cant figure out how to fix it.  they need to be closed after used .
How can I close `CsvReader`? I have tried using `CsvReader.Close()` it doesn't works.

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"].ToString();
            string fileFullName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;//ar csv = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string fileExtensionName = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath + fileFullName);
            var csvTable = new DataTable();
            //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataTable invalidatedTable = new DataTable();
            
            if (fileExtensionName == ".csv")
            {
                using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath + fileFullName)), true))
                {
                    csvTable.Load(csvReader);
                }
           }
```

Comment: _D:.csv_ ? Where is the filename here?

Comment: Check if the file should not be open by default application of the file on which you are performing the operation like excel etc

Comment: You use `System.IO.File.OpenRead`which opens the file, but it is never closed, so next time it is 'in use'! Create the stream with a `using` first, then it will be closed.

Comment: filename is going to be uploaded by fileuploder in .apsx page or web page.

Comment: @PoulBak i have not used system.IO.File.OpenRead instead i have used this all using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;

Comment: It looks like your filenames aren't getting through, at least some of the time.  In a case where your server is handling more than one file at a time (2 concurrent users of your web page) they could both be trying to use the same file path (D:.csv).

Comment: Sure you do, it's in the code you posted!

Comment: @Steve the file name and error is like this System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Sample_Data\sample_data_account.csv' because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: You are creating streamreaders without disposing of them. MSDN: This type implements the IDisposable interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly. To dispose of the type directly, call its Dispose method in a try/catch block. To dispose of it indirectly, use a language construct such as using (in C#) or Using (in Visual Basic). For more information, see the "Using an Object that Implements IDisposable" section in the IDisposable interface topic.

Comment: @TaW I tryed disposing Streamreader  like CsvReader.close() it doesn't works.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but it surely is one issue. You gave arleady put the creation of the `csvReader` in a using clause, where it belongs. But the `streamreader` is created inline and never disposed of. Inlining such code is not a good idea imo as it tends to hard to debug or in this case the disposal in awkward. Split it into a separate line..

Comment: Aslo: 'doesn't work' it not a helpful info. Does it crash or doesn't it compile or does it simply not reslve the original issue..

Comment: @TaW ok i will try writing it differently. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out you need to dispose of the streams, files and readers you are using. It's easiest to do with the using pattern.

```cs
using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath + fileFullName))
{
    using (var stream = new StreamReader(file))
    {
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(stream, true))
        {
            csvTable.Load(csvReader);
        }
    }
}
```

This way all files ought to be closed and disposed.

You can also use the new, more terse format. Personally, I'm not to fond of it:

```cs
using (var file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath + fileFullName));
using (var stream = new StreamReader(file));
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(stream, true));
csvTable.Load(csvReader);
```

Comment: `Personally, I'm not to fond of it` +1

Comment: As i have used this code i am still having an error when I opened the file. but the error is this- System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\Sample_Data\sample_data_account.csv' because it is being used by another process.'